# What should be passed into if() to print 'Hello World'?

Tags: php, logic

What should be passed into the if() to print the output as "Hello World"? [Note: It should execute the else block.]

```
if(?){

} else {
   echo "World";
}
```

Comment: one of `if(0)`, `if(null)`, `if(false)` etc

Comment: if I pass (echo "Hello"). It will not work as echo does not return anything

Comment: ..and even if it did , it would not generate the output requested.

Comment: I have upvoted it because it's unfair to downovte a question just because it's homework. This is a valid question, and it's asked better than many questions I often see on this site.

Comment: I upvoted it because so many experienced developers got it wrong!

Comment: +1 Important lesson SO USERS :1.Read question carefully... and have patience before down voting. 3.don't under estimate new users and home work questions

Comment: @vnshetty this is more likely an interview question rather than a homework. anyway you all but helping a swindle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needs to evaluate to false, and print "Hello" at the same time. `printf` returns the length of outputted string upon success which is **evaluated** to `true` when read in a Boolean context. So reversing that will evaluate to false, executing the else block.

```
if(!printf("Hello ")){

} else {
   echo "World";
}
```

Comment: well this is a trick question ^^. you can if (printf("Hello"), false) { } else { printf("World"); }

Comment: I think that the prof/tutor wants something that echos "Hello " and returns false.

Comment: @BigMike: How is that even legal syntax?

Comment: @BoltClock yes it's C syntax. You're right. But realized later and cannot modify it. But I guess it has served the poupose just right.

Comment: To be pedantic, `printf()` returns the length of the output string that's printed. Printing a non-empty string will, of course, return a truthy value (one that evaluates to true in a Boolean context).

Comment: @BoltClock: Thank you Programmer Nazi (in a good way! I'm one too :D) corrected.

Answer (score 3):

```
!printf("Hello ")
```

By default, printf in 'C' returns true.

Comment: That should work OK if printf is available in php - logic is right and you put in the space after "Hello".

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!printf("Hello "))
{}
else 
{
    echo "World";
}
```

You can do in this way...

Answer (score 1):

There is also an alternate solution for this question:

```
class test{ 
  function __construct()
  { 
     echo "Hello"; 
  } 
} 

if(!new test){ 
}else{ 
 echo "World"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything that evaluates to `FALSE`.

Comment: Ooops. This happens if you don't read the question carefully enough :)

Answer (score 0):

if understands logical result, i mean `TRUE-FALSE`
so any any condition that results in true/false results matters for if so you can use

```
if(true){
echo 'this is executed';
}else{ 
echo "world";
}
```

OR

```
 if(false){
echo 'this is executed';
}else{ 
echo "world";
}
```

i hope this works

Answer (score 0):

```
if(printf("Hello ")) {
}  
else{    
  echo "World";}
```

i think this is enough.....sorry if not